Can a Sorcerer use the Metamagic Options on spells cast from Magic Items?
Under the 2014 rules, it was accepted that you should follow the Casting a Spell rules (2014 PHB, p. 202) when using a Magic Item to cast a spell, as you're still casting the spell, even when it's through it.
Now, the 2024 rules remain largely the same, so the spellcaster should follow the updated Casting Spells rules (2024 PHB, p. 235). From the Chapter 7: Treasure:

Spells Cast from Items
Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell
from the item. The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell and
caster level, doesn’t expend any of the user’s spell slots, and
requires no components unless the item’s description notes otherwise.
The spell uses its normal casting time, range, and duration, and the
user of the item must concentrate if the spell requires Concentration.
Many items, such as Potions, bypass the casting of a spell and confer
the spell’s effects with its usual duration. Certain items make
exceptions to these rules, changing the casting time, duration, or
other parts of a spell. [...]

Given those premises, can a Sorcerer use Metamagic Options on spells cast from Magic Items, including Spell Scrolls?
Note: we had at least three similar questions related to the 2014 rules. I'll link them here for reference:

Can a sorcerer use metamagic when casting a spell via a spell scroll?
Does casting a spell from an item allow you to apply class abilities that are used when casting a spell?
Can a sorcerer use the Quickened Spell metamagic option on a spell cast from a magic wand?


Metamagic Options temporarily modify spells you cast
Casting the spell is the only general prerequsite for most Metamagic Options.

You use the chosen options to temporarily modify spells you cast. To use an option, you must spend the number of Sorcery Points that it costs.

Each option specifies further constraints on the spell. This is variously worded as

When you cast a spell...

and

When you roll damage for a spell...

and, sometimes:

If you make an attack roll for a spell...

The Spells Cast From Items text specifies that a "user" casts the spell from the item.

Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from the item...

Therefore, so long as a "user" has the ability to use Metamagic Options and casts the spell from the item, they can apply pertinent Metamagic Options to the spell.
